How to specialize template function for all derived classes in C++?
I have the code:
class Base {};

template <T>
void Print(const T& obj);

I want to specialize Print for all classes that are derived from Base.
I tried the concept:
template <class T>
concept DerivedFromBase = std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>;

template <DerivedFromBase T>
void Print<T>(…) { … }

But compiler says that it's partial specialization - and functions can't have it.
What are the other solutions and approaches?

Is there a reason you don't want a simple overload: void Print(const Base&);?

@Yksisarvinen The main reason is that this function is declared as template in the huge repository already.

Yes, but you can still overload it. Non-template overloads will be preferred over template overloads.

The compiler is correct, functions can't be partially specialized. What you want instead is to have multiple function templates with different constraints.
For that, it is enough to simply remove the <T>:
template <class T>
concept DerivedFromBase = std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>;

template <DerivedFromBase T>
void Print(…) { … }

Demonstration:
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Base {};

template <typename T>
void Print(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << obj << "\n";
}

template <class T>
concept DerivedFromBase = std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>;

template <DerivedFromBase T>
void Print(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "T is derived from Base\n";
}

int main()
{
    Print(123);
    Print(Base{});
}

Output:
123
T is derived from Base


You don't need to use a template for this.
You can simply define that the print() function receives an object of the Base type
Then automatically you can also send any object that inherits from Base to her.
Example:
using namespace std;
class Base {};
class BaseA:public Base{};
class BaseB:public Base {};
class Foreign{};

void Print(const Base& obj) {};

int main()
{
    BaseA ba;
    BaseB bb;
    Foreign f;
    Print(ba);
    Print(bb);
    Print(f);
}

The Foreign object produced a compilation error. And all other objects that inherit from Base will work properly,
You can try running it.
Successfully!!
